# MS Access - Using a period in field name

Tags: ms-access

is there any way, to use a period (.) in the field name of Access?
For example if I have `foo.bar` as string. Access will give me the following error message:

```
This is not a valid name. Make sure it is a valid parameter or alias name,
that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation, and that the name
is not too long. (Error 3125)
```

I tried escaping it in many ways, like:

```
[foo.bar]
*foo.bar*
'foo.bar'
foo[.]bar
foo*.*bar
foo'.'bar
foo\.bar
```

Nothing seems correct, nothing seems to work. I need to put a period in the field name, I can't replace it with some different character. Is there any way to fix my problem?

Comment: Field names should be **internal** to your application. So *I need to put a period in the field name* should not be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is *No*.

You will have to live with that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

My field names were measurements in millimeters, so I needed field names like 1.1, 1.2, etc. I used 1,1 as the field name and 1.1 as the caption and it worked fine.